# SharePoint Login Credential

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

Currently I try to developed application by using SharePoint that retrieve data from List

Now I try to developed for Login Function, The error display as Below

**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.**

Here with my Source Code

```
string WebUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/devspace";
            string username = txtUsername.Text;
            string pwd = txtPassword.Text;

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(WebUrl);
            Web web = context.Web;

            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray())
                passWord.AppendChar(c);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);
            try
            {
                context.Load(web);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                lblStatus.Text = "Olla " + web.Title;

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
```

Any suggestion for this? Thank in advanced.

**Updated:**

I'm using SharePoint 2016, login via Windows Server AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, you are using SharePoint 2016, then please download and install CSOM with SharePoint 2016 version Nuget package not SharePoint Online:

[Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM/)

And use this code snippet:

```
      ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://example.com/sites/testsite/");  
      clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
            // Get the SharePoint web  
            Web web = clientContext.Web;  

            // Get the SharePoint list collection for the web  
            ListCollection listColl = web.Lists;  

            // Retrieve the list collection properties  
            clientContext.Load(listColl);  

            // Execute the query to the server.  
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  

            // Loop through all the list  
            foreach (List list in listColl)  
            {  
                // Display the list title and ID  
                Console.WriteLine("List Name: " + list.Title + "; ID: " + list.Id);  
            }  
            Console.ReadLine();
```

SharePoint 2016 On Premise not need to use SharePointOnlineCredentials class, just pass username, password, domain as code snippet above.

Comment: At the Page_Load?

Comment: I had Change to .Net Framework 4.6 , but the error still same. The WebURL is with https .

Comment: I had put inside the Global.asax under Application_Start . The Error still Same.

Comment: Are you using the .NET Web Application, please try to create a console application and then test with the code snippet above to see if it works. You can use the latest SharePoint Online CSOM here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

Comment: The error shown : the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials. The response status code is 'OK'. The response headers are 'Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Connection=keep-alive,Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8, Date=Fri, 28 Jun 2019 08:01:12 GMT, Server=Proxy'.

Comment: Did a same code inside Console application whcih have no this error message, please check my modified reply.

Comment: Just Found: the SharePoint 2016 is On Premise and login via Windows Server AD.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2016 ?? Question tag is created with SharePoint-Online.

Comment: SharePoint 2016

Comment: Oh, SharePoint 2016 can't use SharePoint Online Credential, you should specify the SharePoint version inside the question, I will update the code snippet inside reply.

Comment: Done, please check and try.

Comment: I got an Error: Cannot contact site at the specified URL : my url is path is https://xxx/XX/XXXX/

Comment: Make sure the site url is valid and you are using the SharePoint 2016 CSOM.

Comment: Any updates ? please share the progress if possible.

Comment: Its Still display the Error: Cannot contact site at the specified URL

Comment: Can you access the site with the url in browser ?

Comment: The url should be like this http://domainname/sites/sitename, please use the valid url or share it with us for better identify.

Comment: now another issue : The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: going to internet explorer Settings via the menu options -

Tools / Internet Options / Connections / LAN Settings / deselect the Automatically Detect Settings option box and click okay.